LibGit2Sharp unknown certificate lookup failure: 16777280
I am using LibGit2Sharp in a custom git client, works fine on my machine but when I run the same code on a different machine with the same credentials I am getting the error:
unknown certificate lookup failure: 16777280
I've done some googling and looks like its something to do with the authentication certificates but as I'm cloning HTTPS I thought providing the username and password of the gitlab user is enough?
Anyways, can anyone guide me on a resolution here? This is a little above my knowledge and first time using a git API.
Here is the code I'm using. To reiterate, it works perfectly on my own machine but not on another.
public void Clone()
{
    // Notify about the cloning process initiation
    this.OnUpdate?.Invoke(this, new OnUpdateEventArgs
    {
        Severity = LogType.Info,
        Message = $"Cloning the repository {this.RepositoryInfo.Name}"
    });

    try
    {
        // Clone the repository with credentials
        Repository.Clone(this.RepositoryInfo.RemoteRepository, this.RepositoryInfo.LocalRepository.FullName,
            new CloneOptions
            {
                FetchOptions = { CredentialsProvider = (url, user, cred) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials { Username = this.Author.Credentials.UserName, Password = this.Author.Credentials.Password } }
            });

        // Notify about the successful cloning
        this.OnUpdate?.Invoke(this, new OnUpdateEventArgs
        {
            Severity = LogType.Success,
            Message = "Repository cloned successfully."
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Notify about the error during cloning
        this.OnUpdate?.Invoke(this, new OnUpdateEventArgs
        {
            Severity = LogType.Error,
            Message = Errors.GetErrorString(86) + " : " + e.Message
        });
    }
}


This error comes fro the SSL certificate check. It might be that in your environment, the certificate is trusted (e.g. by the company root certificate), but not so on the other machine. If you run a git clone on the other machine, you should get a similar error, or the message that the certificate check has been disabled. Have a look at https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1290, a workaround is provided there (although not working for me, might have another problem).

I can clone using git bash fine on the problem machine, making me scratch my head more!
I have tried cloning via git bash then pulling from the Lib2GitSharp client but the issue persists.

Did you try setting the CertificateCheck callback on your CloneOptions using the delegate in the link? Did that change anything?

It was a firewall issue. Something on the network was blocking the response. Thanks for the help!
